# Rename mongo collection in Go using mgo or bson?

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mgo

I'd like to rename a mongo collection in my Go app. I'm using the mgo driver and it doesn't have a defined method to do this. Does anyone know what the query would be using bson? This is the command I'd like to implement in Go: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/renameCollection/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't used mgo but this looks like exactly what you want to run a raw query.

http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Session.Run

In directly to mongo:

```
db.adminCommand({renameCollection:'yourdb.yourcollection', to:'yourdb.yournewcollection'})
```

Using mgo:

```
session.Run(bson.D{{"renameCollection", "yourdb.yourcollection"}, {"to", "yourdb.yournewcollection"}})
```

Comment: Ah ok. So the second one almost works. But, as per the Mongo specifications, I can apparently only run this command on the admin database. My app creates a separate database with a number of collections, any of which I might need to rename. Does this mean that as long as my app uses a database not called admin, I won't be able to run this command?

Comment: The admin database is a special database inside of mongo. It is where mongo will store administrative settings like users and what they have access to. It isn't created by default (afaik), it's just required that you can access it to run admin commands. Examples: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/